# Express $(523)^{-1}$ as a product of $2$-cycles (or transpositions).

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, permutations

Express $(523)^{-1}$ as a product of *$2$-cycles* (or transpositions).

My solution goes like this:

> It's not specified in the question whether $(523)^{-1}$ is in $S_5$ or not. We assume $(523)^{-1}\in S_5.$ Then $(523)$ represents the permutation $$\beta:1\longrightarrow 1,\\
> 2\longrightarrow 3,\\
> 3\longrightarrow 5, \\
> 4\longrightarrow 4, \\
> 5\longrightarrow 2.$$ Thus, $$\beta^{-1}:1\longrightarrow 1,\\ 2\longrightarrow 5, \\ 3\longrightarrow 2, \\ 4\longrightarrow 4, \\ 5\longrightarrow 3.$$ Thus, $(523)^{-1}=(253)$. If we express this as a product of transpositions then, $(253)=(25)(53)$ (under the convention that if $f$ and $g$ be two permutations then $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$.)

Is the above solution correct? If not then where is it going wrong?

No, this link [Express the following as a product of two-cycles $((142)(3245))^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626967) does not answer my question. In that post, I wanted to verify my procedure for expressing the **inverse of the product of two non- disjoint cycles in transpositions** while in this post I wanted to verify my procedure for expressing the **inverse of single cycle into transpositions**. And this question was posted by me earlier than the link, where I posted the question after I got a confirmation of my process in this post, was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(253)=(325)$ is the correct inverse, but what is $(25)(23)$ equal to? Well, putting 2 into $(25)(23)$ gives 3. Putting in 3 gives you 2 and then 5. Putting in 5 gives you back 2. So $(25)(23)$ is actually not the same thing as $(253)$ but rather $(235)$. Remember permutations are functions and they go right to left. In general,

- $(a_1a_2...a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)...(a_{n-1}a_n)$ (however this is just one of many ways to break a cycle into transpositions)
- $(a_1a_2...a_n)^{-1}=(a_n...a_2a_1)$ (as you know, to find the inverse just map everything backwards)
- and $(a_1a_2...a_n)=(a_na_1...a_{n-1})=(a_2a_3...a_1)$ (because $a_n\to a_1$, it "wraps around", we can shift any number of places in either direction and have the overflow wrap around, and it gives us the same cycle)

Are some useful properties

Cycle notation can frustrating, so feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: Thank you so much for you clarification. The useful properties that you mentioned are under the convention that if $f,g$ be two permutations then $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ , right? If this is the convention then we can actually, break a permutation say, $(a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)... (a_{n-1}a_n)$ and this provides a general strategy to break up a permutation into transpositions, correct? And for the second property you specified, is actually **independent** of all conventions ,correct? It does not depend whether we follow $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ or $f\circ g(x)=g(f(x))$?

Comment: And for the third property as you say, it works under the convention $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ , correct? Finally, a general query :$(523)^{-1}=(253)$ , is this corect , I mean to say, the method I have used for stating $(523)^{-1}=(253)$, is the procedure correct? And I have fixed my solution, is it alright now?If we consider $f\circ g(x)=gf((x))$, then we could have written a permutation $(a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_1a_3)\cdots(a_1a_n) and thus $(253)=(25)(23)$, right?

Comment: @Franklin I personally think of composition as a generalization of multiplication or sorts; they behave in a lot of common ways, but that's besides the point. That is why I use $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ - some people do multiply in the other direction, but that's why I did what I did.

Comment: The procedure you used to get $(523)^{-1}=(253)$ was flawless. Like I mentioned, simply reversing the order would've worked too, but your method demonstrates better that you actually understand what's going on, so that's all fine. Of course, if you multiply the other way, then yes the final part of what you wrote in your last comment is perfectly correct, and also shows that there are multiple way to break any given cycle into transpositions.

Comment: The universe wouldn't fall apart or anything if permutation products had been defined in the other direction - hey, you might not even run out of room every time you write a permutation, like you do when going right to left! But philosophically it just makes makes more sense to have it behave like regular function composition.

Comment: Warning: if you're learning this in a course, your teacher might be one of the people who uses the left to right convention. Even if it is more economical, I don't like it because it's less intuitive, but it's not "wrong" to go in the other direction. I'm sorry, I don't know if that helps but I can try again in the morning when I'm less tired. Apologies

Comment: Why apologies! I should be the one remaining grateful to you. So, the main takeaway from here is that: if the convention is $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ then :$(a_1a_2...a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)...(a_{n-1}a_n)$,$(a_1a_2...a_n)^{-1}=(a_n...a_2a_1),(a_1a_2...a_n)=(a_na_1...a_{n-1})(a_2a_3...a_1)$ holds true,correct? If $f\circ g(x)=g(f(x))$ then the above stated properties might not be true but we can write $(a_1a_2...a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_1a_3)...(a_{n-1}a_n)$, which couldn't be written in the former convention case stated above in this comment, correct?

Comment: Also, assuming $f\circ g(x)=g(f(x))$, we can write $(523)^{-1}=(325)=(32)(25)$, likewise, if we want to evaluate $(27654)^{-1}$, then $(27654)^{-1}=(45672)=(45)(56)(67)(72)$, correct?...

Comment: @Franklin both properties 2 and 3 are independent of the multiplication convention you use. $(27654)=(27)(76)(65)(54)$ as well as $(24)(25)(26)(27)$. Any transposition times itself is the identity, so every transposition's inverse is merely itself. One other property of two permutations $a$ and $b$ is that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, because $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)$ gives the identity. So you could also say $(27654)=(24)(25)(26)(27)$ and then invert both sides to get $(27654)^{-1}=(27)^{-1}(26)^{-1}(25)^{-1}(24)^{-1}=(27)(26)(25)(24)$. It all comes down to which multiplication convention you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the conventions that $(ab) (cd )$ is $(a,b) \circ (c,d)$ and that $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ then your last 2 transpositions should be written in the reverse order.