# Express the following as a product of two-cycles $((142)(3245))^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

Express the following as a product of two-cycles $((142)(3245))^{-1}$

My solution goes like this:

> If $\beta=(142)(3245)$, then $\beta\in S_5$, as nothing is specified about the permutation. So,
>
> $$\beta:1\longrightarrow 4, \\
> 2\longrightarrow 2, \\ 3\longrightarrow 1, \\
> 4\longrightarrow 5, \\
> 5\longrightarrow 3.$$
>
> Now, $$\beta^{-1}: 1\longrightarrow 3, \\
> 2\longrightarrow 2, \\
> 3\longrightarrow 5, \\
> 4\longrightarrow 1, \\
> 5\longrightarrow 4.$$
>
> Thus, $$\begin{align}
> \beta^{-1}&=((142)(3245))^{-1}\\
> &=(1354)(2)\\
> &=(1354)\\
> &=(13)(35)(54).
> \end{align}$$
>
> We can omit a cycle of length $1$ while expressing a permutation a product of cycles(or transpositions) since cycles of length $1$, when multiplied with any permutation keeps the permutation (i.e permutation with which the single cycle of length $1$ is multiplied) unchanged or invariant.

Is the above solution correct (along with my reasonings)? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: You may find the “arrow notation” discussed at [Wikiversity](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Permutation_notation) of use here. In particular, the crossings in a given arrow diagram provide a decomposition into 2-cycles. (For a video version of this concept, see https://youtu.be/geABXC7YpDA.)

Comment: The only bit of "reasoning" you have is for leaving $(2)$ out, I would consider that so obvious that it doesn't need an argument, but what you write is not wrong. Your result seems to be correct.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: To clarify one point for future readers: the work above proceeds under the convention  that permutations act to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "socks and shoes":  $$(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1},$$ we get $$\beta^{-1}=(3245)^{-1}(142)^{-1}=(4235)(241)=(4135)=(45)(43)(41).$$

You're solution is also correct.